# upstart and gnome-session-Unity.log goes mad

Tags: 14.04, upstart

In my upstart folder in `~/.cache/upstart`:

```
-rw-r----- 1 bussiere bussiere  18G août   5 17:59 gnome-session-Unity.log
```

The log goes mad I've tried purge logrotate and reinstall it but nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *really* try to learn why gnome-session is outputting so many logs, but in the meantime, you can do this:

```
rm ~/.cache/upstart/gnome-session-Unity.log
ln -s /dev/null ~/.cache/upstart/gnome-session-Unity.log
```

Comment: for me it was unity-scope-home that gone crazy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem happens when I use my Ubuntu (14.04) as a remote server and do not use screen for a long time. So I turn off X graphics (Unity) service by: sudo service lightdm stop and then do as above (delete gnome-session-Unity.log and take it to /dev/null). If I do not turn off then gnome-session-Unity.log re-appears every time.
Hope this help!